# Video controls and Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('video'), function (video) 
{
      video.addEventListener('play', videoPlayHandler);
      video.addEventListener('pause', videoPauseHandler);
});


function videoPlayHandler(e) {
    e.target.controls = false;
}

function videoPauseHandler(e) {
    e.target.controls = true;
}
```

What is the jquery equivalent to the above?

Am I correct in using the code below?

```
    var $video = $('video');
    $video.on('play', videoPlayHandler);
    $video.on('pause', videoPauseHandler);
```

Note that I used the same videoPlayHandler and videoPauseHandler functions as before.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your code. Closing your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no issue to fix.

Comment: Is e.target in Javascript same as bakery?

Comment: You could use `this.controls = false;` since the `this` refers to the `HTMLVideoElement`

Comment: See here: http://jsbin.com/fuguxed/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I meant jquery not bakery

Comment: Yes both are the same. But rather use `this`.

Comment: Isn't it $(this).controls?

Comment: no. Wrapping `this` into `$()` you're just allowing the jQuery library to nest other jQuery methods and bound them to *that (now jQuery) element* constructor. `controls` is not a jQuery method. But the `HTMLVideoElement` (the `this`) has! a `controls` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mySuperCoolFn(e) {
    // this    = the JS's HTMLElement object (the <video> in your case)
    // $(this) = the jQuery library constructor where JS's `this` is passed as argument

    // JS:
    e.target.controls = false;
    // or better:
    this.controls = false;
    // or the same as above, just in pure jQuery:
    $(this).prop("controls", false);
    // or mixing jQuery and JS: 
    $(this)[0].controls = false;
}
$video.on('play', mySuperCoolFn);
```

is the exact same as:

```
$video.on('play', function(e){
    // this    = the JS's HTMLElement object (the <video> in your case)
    // $(this) = the jQuery library constructor where JS's `this` is passed as argument

    // JS:
    e.target.controls = false;
    // or better:
    this.controls = false;
    // or the same as above, just in pure jQuery:
    $(this).prop("controls", false);
    // or mixing jQuery and JS:
    $(this)[0].controls = false;
});
```